# How to disable native keyboard in Ionic 2 application?

Tags: ionic-framework, keyboard, ionic2

In my Ionic 2 application I would like to build "virtual" keyboard with a special characters (like α, β, ζ, ...) and I need to disable native keyboard for my input field.

```js
Keyboard.onKeyboardShow()
  .subscribe(data => {
    setTimeout(() => Keyboard.close(), 0);
});
```

Code above doesn't helps because:
1. Keyboard shows before hiding :frowning:
2. Input field loses focus

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I think it can be done. Disable the input field so that the default keyboard wouldnt activate , then add a `click` event to initiate your own keyboard. Style the disabled input field to change the look.

```
<ion-input type="text" name="name" disabled (click)="ownKeyboard()" >
```

Comment: No, this will disable the input field totally not keyboard

Comment: this would disable keyboard  entering. You can change the style and add events to have your keyboard take charge.